# react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js could not be found

Tags: react-native

when i run my project in react native android i got this issue

> Error: Cannot find module 'react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15) at
>   Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:16:19) at
>   makeMakeHMRConfig7
>   (/home/local/MPLLC/malwinder.singh/demoApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/babel-bridge.js:120:31)
>   at Object.
>   (/home/local/MPLLC/malwinder.singh/demoApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/babel-bridge.js:49:24)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:416:10) at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function)
>   [as .js]
>   (/home/local/MPLLC/malwinder.singh/demoApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
>   at Module.load (module.js:343:32) at Function.Module._load
>   (module.js:300:12) at Module.require (module.js:353:17) at require
>   (internal/module.js:12:17)

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: answer below worked for me absolutely fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a problem with react transform hmr you have to run this command.

```
npm install react-transform-hmr --save
```

Comment: no I didn't fix it... yarn is "yarn add --dev react-transform-hmr"?

Comment: @shinriyo You can find more answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659866/unable-to-resolve-module-react-transform-hmr-lib-index-js